# UIStepper to create number of buttons programmatically

Tags: swift

This is part of my viewDidLoad:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // stepper settings
    dayStepper.autorepeat = true
    dayStepper.maximumValue = 28
    dayStepper.minimumValue = 14
    dayStepper.value = 26
    dayStepperLabel.text = "\(Int(dayStepper.value)) days"

    for index in 1...totalDays {

        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = index
        button.setTitle("\(index)", forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        .....
```

I created a UIStepper that sets the totalDays... minimum 14, maximum 28. So if the user selects 26 days... there will be 26 buttons (and 26 textfields) created programmatically.

With a 'fixed' number of totalDays everything works fine. The UIStepper works also... (the label is changing oké). My question... if a user selects 26 (with the stepper) I want the screen rebuilt itself with 26 buttons and 26 textfields... if the user selects 16, I want the screen to rebuilt automatically to show just 16 buttons and textfields (without loosing the info in the textfields).

What is the best way to do that? I imagine I can do that with a hide property... but then still the buttons and textfield are there. So there must be a better way... Thanks, Jan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` to display your buttons. Using the delegate methods, you can automatically bind the number of cells (each of which contains a button) to a value that you've dynamically set via the stepper.

You can subclass the cells to get them looking the way you want.

Comment: thanks Mark... if I choose an UITableView... can I make a grid of 3 x 10 cells? (each cell consists of one button and one textfield) Than I can use the same 'layout' that I currently have...

Comment: You'd definitely want to use a UICollectionView for that. You should be able to keep the same visual layout, it might just take a bit of code refactoring ;)

Comment: can you explain why you have such a strong preference for the UICollectionView instead of the UITableView? I found some examples and tutorials online... gonna give them a try.

Comment: A table is for a table (i.e. a 1xn grid), a uicollection is for a grid of things (mxm), which is what you want.